# CustomPainter canvas covering up pageview controller

Tags: flutter

I made horizontally scrollable pageview that shows different pictures and added custom border to it with custompainter class, but problem is the canvas covers up pageview controller so my pageview is no longer scrollable, any way to make it scrollable again?
[Current Pageview with borders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qbrsk.png)

```
Stack(
  children: <Widget>[
    PageView.builder(
      controller: adController,
      itemCount: ads.length,
      onPageChanged: (idx) {
        setState(() {
          _currentAd = idx;
        });
      },
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        //Slide of carousel, gets data by list
        ix = index;
        id = ads[ix].getIdex();
        return AdTile(
          imgPath: ads[ix].getAssetPath(),
          desc: ads[ix].getDescript(),
        );
      },
    ),
    //Top curved border of Calculator,more section carousel
    ClipPath(
      clipper: WaveClipperTwo(
        flip: true,
        reverse: false,
      ),
      child: Container(
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        height: 85.0,
        color: Color(0xfff8931f).withOpacity(0.4),
      ),
    ),
    ClipPath(
      clipper: WaveClipperTwo(
        flip: true,
        reverse: false,
      ),
      child: Container(
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        height: 70.0,
        color: Color(0xfff8931f),
      ),
    ),
    //bottom curved border of calculator,more section carousel
    CustomPaint(
      size: Size(MediaQuery.of(context).size.width, 377),
      painter: SecondWave(),
    ),
    GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        showDialog(
            context: context,
            builder: (BuildContext context) {
              //this links which popup should popup when clicked on slider
              return cmpopups[id];
            });
      },
      child: CustomPaint(
        size: Size(MediaQuery.of(context).size.width, 377),
        painter: FirstWave(),
      ),
    ),
    Positioned(
      bottom: 10.0,
      child: SizedBox(
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            //defines length of indicator dots, counts how much items there are
            //in data.dart list and add dots accordingly/equally
            for (int i = 0; i < ads.length; i++)
              _currentAd == i ? adIndicator(true) : adIndicator(false),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ],
);
```

Note: I added custom border outside of item builder because border stays still while inside items slide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to encapsulate your `CustomPaint` inside an `IgnorePointer`.

You could also manage both Top and Bottom as `ClipPath` as in this solution:

[image]

### Full source code

```
import 'package:faker/faker.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_hooks/flutter_hooks.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'PageView Demo',
      home: HomePage(),
    ),
  );
}

class HomePage extends HookWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final _adController = usePageController(initialPage: 0);
    final _currentPage = useState(0);
    return Scaffold(
        body: Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        PageView(
          controller: _adController,
          onPageChanged: (page) => _currentPage.value = page,
          children: ads
              .map(
                (ad) => Card(
                  child: Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(24.0),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      image: DecorationImage(
                        fit: BoxFit.cover,
                        image: AssetImage(ad.assetPath),
                      ),
                    ),
                    child: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        const SizedBox(height: kTopHeight),
                        Text(
                          ad.title,
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 32.0,
                            color: Colors.white,
                            backgroundColor: Colors.black54,
                          ),
                        ),
                        const SizedBox(height: 16.0),
                        Text(
                          ad.description,
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 24.0,
                            color: Colors.white,
                            backgroundColor: Colors.black54,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              )
              .toList(),
        ),
        Positioned(
          top: 0.0,
          child: ClipPath(
            clipper: WaveClipperTop(),
            child: Container(
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                height: kTopHeight,
                color: kMainColor),
          ),
        ),
        Positioned(
          top: kWaveWidth,
          child: ClipPath(
            clipper: WaveClipperTop(),
            child: Container(
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              height: kTopHeight,
              color: kMainColor.withOpacity(kWaveOpacity),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Positioned(
          bottom: kWaveWidth,
          child: ClipPath(
            clipper: WaveClipperBottom(),
            child: Container(
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              height: kBottomHeight,
              color: kMainColor.withOpacity(kWaveOpacity),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Positioned(
          bottom: 0.0,
          child: ClipPath(
            clipper: WaveClipperBottom(),
            child: Container(
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              height: kBottomHeight,
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
            showDialog(
              context: context,
              builder: (BuildContext context) => AlertDialog(
                title: Text(ads[_currentPage.value].title),
                content: Text(ads[_currentPage.value].description),
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
        Positioned(
          bottom: 10.0,
          left: 0.0,
          right: 0.0,
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: List.generate(
              ads.length,
              (i) => Text(
                '⚫',
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: _currentPage.value == i ? kMainColor : Colors.black12,
                ),
              ),
            ).toList(),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ));
  }
}

class WaveClipperTop extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    return Path()
      ..lineTo(0, size.height * 3 / 4)
      ..quadraticBezierTo(
          size.width * 2 / 5, size.height / 4, size.width / 2, size.height / 2)
      ..quadraticBezierTo(
          size.width * 3 / 4, size.height * 9 / 8, size.width, size.height / 2)
      ..lineTo(size.width, 0)
      ..close();
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(covariant CustomClipper<Path> oldClipper) => false;
}

class WaveClipperBottom extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    return Path()
      ..moveTo(0, size.height)
      ..lineTo(0, size.height * 4 / 5)
      ..quadraticBezierTo(size.width * 11 / 40, size.height * 21 / 40,
          size.width / 2, size.height * 11 / 20)
      ..quadraticBezierTo(
          size.width * 31 / 40, size.height * 23 / 40, size.width, 0)
      ..lineTo(size.width, size.height)
      ..close();
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(covariant CustomClipper<Path> oldClipper) => false;
}

class Ad {
  final String assetPath;
  final String title;
  final String description;

  Ad({this.assetPath, this.title, this.description});
}

// CONFIGURATION

const kMainColor = Colors.amber;
const kWaveWidth = 20.0;
const kWaveOpacity = .6;
const kTopHeight = 80.0;
const kBottomHeight = 160.0;
const kBottomPadding = 200.0;

// DUMMY DATA

final faker = Faker();
final ads = List.generate(
  4,
  (index) => Ad(
    assetPath: 'assets/spiders/$index.jpg',
    title: faker.person.name(),
    description: faker.lorem.sentence(),
  ),
).toList();
```

Comment: Thank you, Ignore something was back on my mind but couldn't really find it, helped a lot!